# How to merge rows of strings against a custom key

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have this raw table in pandas that I am trying to shorten by merging multiple rows of one string column into one row against a key.

For example, lets say this is my raw data:

| StudentName | Class |
| --- | --- |
| Adam | I |
| Mathew | II |
| Sheldon | I |
| Albert | I |
| Angelica | II |
| Maya | II |
| Ashley | III |

Into an output something like this:

| Class | Student | Count of Students |
| --- | --- | --- |
| I | Adam, Sheldon, Albert | 3 |
| II | Mathew, Angelica,Maya | 3 |
| III | Ashley | 1 |

I tried using group by but that solution is giving me results in different rows and am not able to put different rows into one, what is the right way to approach this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
df.groupby('Class').agg(StudentNames=('StudentName': lambda x: ','.join(x)), Counts=('StudentName', lambda x: len(x) )  )
```